# Real Roots of$ x^{10} + a_9x^9 + a_8x^8 +.....+a_1x -5$

Tags: real-analysis, arithmetic

The equation $ x^{10} + a_9x^9 + a_8x^8 +.....+a_1x - 5 =0 $ where $a_i $are real numbers.

Then 
1. Must have one real root of multiplicity one

2. Must have atleast two real roots (distinct or repeated)

3 must have atlest 4 real roots (distinct or repeated)

4.need not have real root

My attempt: since leading coefficient and last term are given so, product of roots is negative. Thus option 4 is eliminated. But I need suggestions for other options thanks

Comment: If there is at least one real root then there are at least two.

Comment: At $x=0$ the polynomial (call it $P(x)$) evaluates to $-5$. Since the leading term is $x^{10}$, for $x\to \pm \infty$, $P(x)\to +\infty$, so it must cross the real axis at least twice

Comment: Eliminate 3), the example is easy.

Comment: @AndréNicolas "if there is at least one real root then there are atleast two" plz explain sir. Eg x^3+x+1 has  one root but not two. They have to be in pairs, is that what u mean?

Comment: There need not be a natural pairing. Here is one argument. If $r$ is a real root, then $x-r$ divides the polynomial The quotient has degree $9$ (odd) so has a root. Or in our case we can use the argument of DepeHb.

Comment: By the way, there need not be a real root of multiplicity $1$. Example, $(x-\sqrt[10]{5})^5(x+\sqrt[10]{5})^5$.